# How do I write unit tests for subclass with parameterized base class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit-3.0

Given that I have a class in one assembly called GBase with a constructor that takes 2 parameters and a subclass of GBase (call it GDerived) that takes the same parameters, how do I separate these so that I can unit test the subclass?

In OtherAssembly:

```
public class GBase
{
  public GBase(ParamType1 param1, ParamType2 param2)
  {
    ...
  }

  protected ParamType1 SomeProperty { get; set; }

// other stuff
}
```

In ThisAssembly:

```
public class GDerived : GBase
{
  public GDerived(ParamType1 param1, ParamType2 param2)
      :base(param1, param2)
  {
    // new code 

    SomeProperty = newCalculatedValue;

    // other stuff
  }

// other stuff
}
```

The original GBase class is legacy code, as is the general structure of the program -- changing the structure is out of the question due to the codebase size (10k lines plus) - none of which has ever had a unit test written for it until very recently.

So now I want to write a test (using NUnit) for the subclass constructor to verify the correct properties are populated with the correct values. Note the test classes are in the same project as the tested classes.

```
[TestFixture]
public class GDerivedTests
{
  [Test]
  public void GDerivedConstructor_ValidParams_PropertiesSetCorrectly()
  {
    var newGDerived = new GDerived(parameter1, parameter2);

    Assert.That(SomeProperty == parameter1;
  }
}
```

This is a very crude rep of what we have to deal with, and there are cases other than setting a property in the base class we need to test. I just don't even know for sure where to start. I have Michael Feathers' book Working Effectively with Legacy Code but it doesn't seem to cover this pervasive "design pattern", used extensively throughout the code we are dealing with. Is it because it's so simple any blinking idjyot should know how to deal with it, or is it because it's a rare case? Somehow I don't think it's either, but I could be wrong...

One possible method I thought of is to extract an interface for the base class and mock the base class constructor - but I'm not sure of the details on how to do that. Note we are all relative newbies at unit testing on the team, no experience to draw on. Not coding newbies, just unit test newbies.

TIA,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with: keep it simple! In your example, the only thing you can test is `SomeProperty`. Everything else is in the base class which you seem that you don't want to test so a test method `GDerivedConstructor_ValidParams_PropertiesSetCorrectly()` makes no sense. Long-term, it could be wise having tests for it though.

Tests typically contain three elements known as AAA: Arrange, Act and Assert. So write your test like this:

```
[Test]
public void GDerivedTestOfSomeProperty()
{
    // arrange
    ParamOfSomeProperty expected = ValueWeAreLookingFor; // this is something that you
                                                         // have in newCalculatedValue

    // act
    GDerived actual = new GDerived(
        AnyValueThatMakesThisTestWork1, // maybe null?
        AnyValueThatMakesThisTestWork2); // maybe null?

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual.SomeProperty);
}
```

That's it for a start. Go from here. You will soon see that you get lots of redundant code so you possibly want to re-engineer that after a while.

Mocking makes sense for testing the base class or when the base class does some weird stuff with the objects that are injected. In this case, pass in mocks instead of real objects. I personally would use a mocking framework that does all the job for you and you can also use this for testing the base class itself. A famous example is [moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart).

On a side note: you'll be better off if you move your test classes into its own project. Testing code should not be released for various reasons plus building, testing and deploying may get easier if they are separated.

Comment: Even as a relative newbie, I am familiar with the approach and the frameworks.  :)  We are using NUnit and Moq to start with. We are adding tests to new code added to an existing application that has never seen a unit test until recently.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent response. As it turns out we had other problems that were masked by a "bug" in Resharper. There was a Resharper option (Shadow-copy assemblies being tested) that was preventing the real errors from being reported. After disabling that, the real errors are dependencies in the GBase class on other classes in still other assemblies. We have our work cut out for us...

Comment: As to the side note, there are perfectly valid arguments for both approaches. We are still debating the best approach.

Comment: For anyone who reads this and cares, it turns out we need to put unit tests in their own directory in order to get access to all the projects in our solution. Debate resolved...